# Add a BBC Podcast to iTunes

Tags: itunes, windows, podcasts

I used to subscribe to BBC podcasts by clicking on the 'Subscribe' icon and selecting iTunes/IOS - simple.  Now when I do it, the programme opens up Winamp and nothing is added to iTunes.  Has something changed?  Should I be directing this question to the BBC?  I am just using my PC and Windows 7, nothing fancy.

Comment: This is really a windows question - how to open a download (or a rss: protocol description) in another program so better on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Winamp [has claimed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app) podcast/RSS feeds, `rss://`, on your computer. This means when an podcast/RSS feed is clicked, Winamp is launched rather than iTunes.

The [BBC's Podcast help](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/help#podcasts) suggests copying and pasting the podcast link directly into iTunes:

> ### Subscribing using iOS, Android or Window
>
> Select your operating system. Once you have installed your chosen
>   software simply click on the relevant button and the software will do
>   the rest.
>
> ### Subscribe using a feed reader
>
> Clicking on RSS will take you to the actual podcast feed page.
>
> Some browsers may display instructions at the top of the page in which
>   case simply follow them.
>
> Or, you can copy and paste the feed URL into a new feed in your
>   podcast software or feed reader - just look for buttons or links
>   marked "Add feed" or "Subscribe".

Comment: Thanks Graham, but I wanted to avoid having to do it manually.  As I said, It used to work, but doesn't any longer.  I have now found out how to do it from within iTunes, so am a hapy bunny again.  Thanks for your time.